# geo location with safari

Tags: dictionary, safari, geolocation

1. This will appear to a duplicate question but please consider this. I am doing an application with google map. my client need to load the places around the visitor, so i am trying to use geolocation. But all the google results and stackoverflow results shows, its impossible with wired network in Safari to get the location. Is there any other possibility that it can be implemented?(i have tried to use Modernizr and the Webshims even its example fails in safari, so i think no hope for that too)
2. my reference website is foursquare.com. its work perfect with map. is it using google map  geolocation?

Comment: I think this may be along the lines of what you're looking for: http://www.geoiptool.com/

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i dont know is this the exact answer. But i find out a solution for my problem. I used geoLiteCity.dta database to get the location details from the IP addess. Then i Used  geocoder to get the location in the map from that address. I am not sure is it a proper way or not, but as far as i am getting the locations. If there is any better way please let me know. Thanks